# get min and max value from dynamoDb using node.js sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

i used amazon dynamoDb for storing my data. i created database like this

> Partition key : userid    ,    Type : String
>
> Sort key    : score   , Type : Number

and i inserted some rows.

> manaf1      | 100
>
> manaf2      | 500
>
> manaf1      | 200
>
> manaf1      | 600

i need to get max & min score for selected user. This is my code

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    region: "myRegion"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    "TableName": "tableName",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "#userid = :userid ",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#userid": "userid"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":userid": {
            "S": "manaf1"
        }
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
    }
});
```

But i got error when running this code.

```
Unable to query. Error: {
  "message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2016-08-31T06:12:13.825Z",
  "requestId": "S1DFFJNDNVV4KQNSO5AEDASFMVJF66Q9ASHDFUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 0
}
```

i need output like

> manaf1  minimum score = 100
>
> manaf1  maximum score = 600

1. is it possible to get max or min of a number field from dynamoDb?
2. what is the issue related with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please change the ExpressionAttributeValues as mentioned below. This should resolve the error.

```
ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':userid' : 'manaf1'        
    }
```

To sort the score in descending order, you can set the ScanIndexForward to false.

```
var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditionExpression : 'userid = :userid',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':userid' : 'manaf1'        
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false
};
```

> If ScanIndexForward is true, DynamoDB returns the results in the order
>   in which they are stored (by sort key value). This is the default
>   behavior. If ScanIndexForward is false, DynamoDB reads the results in
>   reverse order by sort key value, and then returns the results to the
>   client.
>
> Type: Boolean

To sort the score in ascending order, you can set the ScanIndexForward to true.

Using **ScanIndexForward** you can get the MIN and MAX score record as first record in the result.

Comment: what if we dont have KeyConditionExpression?